# Validar con codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, validación

No tengo mucha experiencia, y a la hora de querer hacer una validación utilizando la libreria de codeigniter, me aparecen dificultades. Prácticamente no se realiza la validación. No hay informe de ningún tipo.

Les agradezco desde ya su colaboración, toda ayuda es bienvenida.

P/D: agregué código como respuesta, porque no tengo permiso de hacerlo en una sola publicación.

**Autoload**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');
```

**Controlador**

```
public function agregarProductos(){

    
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('codProducto', 'CodProducto', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $result = $this->m->agregarProductosM();
        $array = $result;


    }else{

        $array = array('error' => true, 
                        'codigo_error' => form_error('codigo')
                    );

    }


echo json_encode($array);

}
```

---

**Vista**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Código: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="codProducto" id="CodProducto"value="">
                    <span id="codigo_error" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

```js
    <script>    
$('#btnSave').click(function(){
            var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
            var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
        
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    method: 'post',
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success: function(response){
                        if(response.success){
                            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                            $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                            if(response.type=='add'){
                                var type = 'agregado'
                            }else if(response.type=='update'){
                                var type ="modificado"
                            }
                            $('.alert-success').html('Producto '+type+' correctamente').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
                            mostrar();
                        }

                        if(response.error)
                        {
                            if(response.codigo_error != ''){
                                $('#codigo_error').html(response.codigo_error);

                            }   else{
                                $('#codigo_error').html('');

                            }
                        }


                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('No se pudo registrar');
                    }
                });
            
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la función `form_error()` recibe como parámetro el nombre del campo.

En tú caso:

```php
$array = array('error' => true, 
    'codigo_error' => form_error('codProducto')
);
```

ref: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#showing-errors-individually